# Stuck to run Selenium RC script simultaneously in multiple browsers

Tags: java, selenium-rc, multiple-browsers

I am working in selenium RC with Java+Junit+Eclipse.
For my project I have developed script which will run in only one browser i.e Firefox through the below code..

```
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
   selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,"*firefox","http://www.google.com");
   FinalTestSuite.selenium.start();
   selenium.windowFocus();
   selenium.windowMaximize();
}
```

Now I am stuck because requirement came to run the script simultaneously in multiple browsers.
I didn't find any helpful article..
Please anyone working on this same scenario...HELP! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/) to run a script in multiple browsers. Also you can refer [this](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_grid_as_infrastructural_tool.htm) blog regarding its setup configuration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a runner which will run the suite containing `setUp()`
Pass the browser name by variable to setup.

You can run the code multiple times with multiple RC server started on different ports.

e.g. My projects runs through ant so i pass -Dargument=*firefox on command prompt then my test cases run on firefox browser also you can pass the port number and host ip.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to use for parallel execution is TestNG. But since you are using Junit , the following link may help you in that.

http://blog.varunin.com/2011/07/running-selenium-tests-on-different.html